# mapview using api v2 key

Tags: android

I am using mapview in layout and api v2 key but map is not displayed. My question is...Can I use v2
key in mapview or I will have to use mapfragment.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" 
    android:enabled="true" 
    android:apiKey="my_apikey" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.fpa"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name="com.example.fpa.GMapsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

</manifest>
```

getting output as follows:
[image]

Comment: Dont reveal ur key anywhere.. i have edited it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map that you're using `com.google.android.maps.MapView` is a **v1** of Google Map API. Unfortunately, it is officially deprecated.

You should use the new version of [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/) which is Version 2

> My question is...Can I use v2 key in mapview?

Maps V1 key depends on MD5 key (If I'm not mistaken) while V2 depends on SHA1 Key. Therefore, you cannot use that.

> I will have to use mapfragment

Well, why not?

Here's a tutorial for [Google Map V2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)

Comment: I have implemented map using mapview and now I have to change it for mapfragmet...Any other idea to continue with mapview ?

Comment: No, There's also a MapView for v2 but you have to pass their lifecycle. If you're preferring to MapView of V1, I would say 'No' because google stops key generation for old version and the map would not work at all.

Comment: Personally after fighting for 12 hours, I think your answer is actually the answer of most of map problems for beginner. I was mixing up key of v2 and library of v1. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use this code ans set the target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8

public class ActivityGoogleMap extends MapActivity {

```
@Override  
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    //to add zoom in and zoom out default buttons  
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
}
```

}

Comment: can you confirm that you are using the API key which is generated on your system? Because it is different for different system.