# Dynamically adding Map Fragment into an activity using FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I have been searching lot about adding Map fragment into an activity and performing fragment transaction to add and remove the map fragment just like normal fragment.I found lot of older post on stackoverflow but most of them user getMap() method to get googleMap object but current version of map does not have getMap() method but it has getMapAsync() so the solution I found was not the solution I was looking for.
I found someone using this also 
`GoogleMap map=((MapFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap()` but here also getMap() is undefined in current version of map.
So can anyone please give me a proper guidance to achieve.
Here is the code, how I want to achieve this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Fragment{
GoogleMap map;
MapView v;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);
    return view;
}
```

}

Where activity_main is a layout which contains Map fragment:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.kamaloli.mapdemo.MainActivity">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.kamaloli.mapdemo.MainActivity" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So all I want to do is I want to add this Fragment into another activity using Fragment transaction like normal fragment.

Comment: You can put this map fragment in a fragment then replace activity with this fragment

Comment: Can you give example?

Comment: sure, wait a minute.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029325/mapview-using-api-v2-key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this map fragment to a Fragment (MapFragment) layout file:

```
     <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Declare mapview and googlemap publicly :

```
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap googleMap;
```

Add below code to onViewCreated():

```
mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.onResume();
mapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

Implement OnMapReadyCallback to your fragment and add this method:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
}
```

Add a container in the activity_main.xml:

```
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="+@id/container"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent" 
        android:layout_height = "match_parent">

       // Add all activity contents here

     <FrameLayout/>
```

Replace this container with MapFragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager():
fm.beginTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new MapFragment()).commit();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its not working. It is saying incompatible type "Cant convert Fragment to GoogleMap "object and getMap() method is also not available but getMapAsync() is present.

Comment: I've changed my answer. Now you don't have to use getMap(). It also has become deprecated. Instead use getMapAsync. Moreover, you should not call a fragment inside a fragment. Use mapview instead.  I've changed my answer largely.  Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Yes worked like charm. Thank you tahsinRupam for your  help and time.